# How to estimate the break points of a piecewise regression in Stata?

Tags: stata, piecewise

I'm trying to do a piecewise regression in Stata, but I don't have the exact location of the break points in my data. Is there any way to estimate these?
Also, I'm not sure if there are 1 or 2 breakpoints. How can I find this out?

All commands I tried require me to set the breakpoints manually. However, those are just my estimation and not sure if it is the correct location

Comment: If you don't have a clear idea of what the breakpoints are, it is not clear why piecewise regression is of use or interest, but that said, the question is here is statistical rather than about programming.